# Identity Server 4 not return error description to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I have an Identity server 4 project which follows the documentation on how to display the errors

**Home Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;

    public HomeController(IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction)
    {
        _interaction = interaction;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Error(string errorId)
    {
        var vm = new ErrorViewModel();
        var message = await _interaction.GetErrorContextAsync(errorId);
        if (message != null)
            vm.Error = message;
        return View("Error", vm);
    }
}
```

The Identity server itself is giving some good information in the logs

```
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Unknown client or not enabled: 3CCF1B2D-D064-4A1B-BFD4-57E0451575C7.apps.biz
{
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "RequestedScopes": "",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "3CCF1B2D-D064-4A1B-BFD4-57E0451575C7.test.apps.biz",
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc",
          "response_type": "id_token",
          "scope": "openid profile",
          "response_mode": "form_post",
          "nonce": "636589548258549622.YzMwMzRkNjAtYWU2Ni00ODlmLTg3ZWQtNmRmOThhYjcyN2JlZWFkYjk2MjEtNDAxNC00ZTQ1LWEzZTAtNTZmMWIyNDhkZjg1",
          "state": "CfDJ8FDPGFWZWNNOmnYDxcFlnVDZgaOG1kNakiXQF48y_4gnSxuIVAVQmMJ_4j9SUZz1TXGJDt4-8EKmoxLXuw3SZgyc5fy1ODzdS0Njd68T1W9dGxt8rFNrUF0njKk3XrSRTeJ45geS_uOL4w89OVupVq4UtHVbKxj3UMZLCn4W-BAXpXfo43KIT8RvxICMjbNtvPM1toEmMSlfdic6T6EZoxXpwim919xMLeQCY0S7QZdbc9DFfUfJkVYsLrofiBvQtZLfQjRQNp_7MiYFz_C4IQ7BAupErvZpcNvpBhQJWIt8BKlACVfKLHbvO6M0FKqa9A",
          "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
          "x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0"
        }
      }
```

and

```
 fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
  Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc
{
        "ClientId": "testclient",
        "ClientName": "testclient",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "RequestedScopes": "",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "testclient",
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200/signin-oidc",
          "response_type": "code id_token",
          "scope": "openid profile",
          "response_mode": "form_post",
          "nonce": "636589567957415216.ZjYyZTU3MTEtZWRhZi00N2RhLWI1MjQtZThlZjk4NjY2NmJmZDQ4ZmUzNzQtMTI3MS00YTdiLTgzNDUtYThlMWU2NzcxMmM5",
          "state": "CfDJ8FDPGFWZWNNOmnYDxcFlnVByKSJA-wSjaBBIB2p-d1oUhuZNGBiD1gOFpnyxevmIKxNY1Hf15vlbpgLZoEVQ8O7UhyOpR1ANgUhhyl9nL4M63-2am7F1LJf9hwijkS0_WpxxJ-jYHlq4r99fS2tcaPFZjAG_UNjWYgTshD5Kps3czFvJOG04plaCn2zcKCX5AGgTVnxlG7__hi1ifn-xOipynq5nHBIasMT6doCmpjktAqx7AOK4C1D__YbVMkcRhC70qYFCfoSNhpUrROXZobP6GxYXd1y5EEbA_oXJjmePFdEL-MFQp0o5D_H_mXsU1g",
          "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
          "x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0"
        }
      }
```

However the only information isnt returned to my controller by `GetErrorContextAsync` so only the error name can be displayed to the user.

[image]

The description of the error isn't filled out at all.

How do i get at the very least description populated?

I am looking for a way of displaying some sensible information for the developers here.  However every error seams to return unauthorized_client so i cant tell the developer that its a problem with the redirect URI vs an invalid client id.

```
if (vm.Error.Error == "unauthorized_client") vm.Error.ErrorDescription = "Contact plugin developer.";
```

Note: Redirect URI one does appear to return a description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended by design. You can't access to the reason for `unathorized_client` in your controller.

you can also check the source to see what's going on.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// check for valid client
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var client = await _clients.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(request.ClientId);
if (client == null)
{
    LogError("Unknown client or not enabled", request.ClientId, request);
    return Invalid(request, OidcConstants.AuthorizeErrors.UnauthorizedClient);
}
```

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Validation/AuthorizeRequestValidator.cs#L150

Comment: eah?   Why cant i access the reason?  Why wouldn't i be able to tell the developers that the redirect uri they are sending is bad.  Currently i have developers contacting me to check the logs for them which is IMO a waste of my time.

Comment: I don't know exactly. Maybe it's for security reasons.

Comment: Think we should drag this over to the Issue forum?  I can understand some of the messages not being displayed to users but i should be able to override it a bit to what i think is acceptable.

Comment: I don't think they change anything since this is the way IdentityServer is working since previous versions

Comment: Doesnt mean it cant change they have already fixed one issue i sent them.

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2218  worse thing they can say is working as intended and i will just hard code it when its null.