# How to send an error response back to OAuth2 client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

Identity Server 4 redirects to the `AccountController` for login, once the user is validated the `HttpContext.SignInAsync` method is called and then a Redirect to the ReturnUrl is performed.

However, in some cases there is an `internal server error` that needs to be sent back to the original client instead of being displayed to the end user in a View. In this case, I would like to issue a standard `OAuth2` error response but I don't see a way of doing this.

Update:

I've added more information. This part of the OAuth 2.0 spec is what I'm referring to. Can Identity Server do this or do I have to manually build the URL from the RedirectUri.

An example of the RedirectUri based on this spec would be this:

For example, the authorization server redirects the user-agent by sending the following HTTP response:

```
   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
   Location: https://client.example.com/cb?error=access_denied&state=xyz
```

Section 4.1.2.1 of the OAuth 2.0 spec states:

```
    If the request fails due to a missing, invalid, or mismatching
redirection URI, or if the client identifier is missing or invalid,
the authorization server SHOULD inform the resource owner of the
error and MUST NOT automatically redirect the user-agent to the
invalid redirection URI.

If the resource owner denies the access request or if the request
fails for reasons other than a missing or invalid redirection URI,
the authorization server informs the client by adding the following
parameters to the fragment component of the redirection URI using the
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format.
```

Comment: Maybe you can also post it as an issue in [IdentityServer4 repo](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) (and link this q there).

Comment: In the current flow, is the user returned to the client when this happens? And can you tell something about these 'internal server error's, when and why do they occur?

Comment: You could override the AuthorizeRequestValidator?

Comment: The "internal server error" was just a "what if". Its not actually occurring. If there is an "internal server error" how do I send a notification back to the middleware so it can decide how to handle the process.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible, this is intended by design of Identity Server 4.

If you check source code https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/AuthorizeRequestValidator.cs#L146 you will find:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// check for valid client
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var client = await _clients.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(request.ClientId);
if (client == null)
{
    LogError("Unknown client or not enabled", request.ClientId, request);
    return Invalid(request, OidcConstants.AuthorizeErrors.UnauthorizedClient, "Unknown client or client not enabled");
}
```

This was inspired by this answer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752059/identity-server-4-not-return-error-description-to-controller).